# why does this question still exist i want to delete it

Tags: javascript, html, css

why does this question still exist i want to delete it

Comment: What is this? Are you asking a question or providing an answer?

Comment: `@Dimitri Mentus`: Instead of commenting your own question, please edit the question and add the code snippet in there.

Comment: whats a code snippet?

Comment: Please read [ask] and post a [mre] of the code you've attempted. We really can't help you if you don't post a clear question with your work-in-progress code :)

Comment: i kinda understand thanks for the tip @AStombaugh

Comment: It's not clear what your questions is. Your first sentence sounds like an answer to something and your second is bolded asking not be down voted. ???

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cursor:none;` property here:

```css
.box {
width:100px;
height:100px;
border: 1px solid black;
cursor:none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: @DimitriMentus Can you please tell what exactly you want?

Comment: It's not possible to "lock" or "freeze" the cursor. You can hide it using the css-property `cursor: none;`.

Comment: id is used when you want to identify an element uniquely while class is used if you want multiple elements.

Comment: then how in like some games they can block your cursor from going to certain places
so its impossible to make a force field?

Comment: @DimitriMentus That could be done in any number of ways depending on the architecture of the game and the platform it runs on.